# Using network printer on a dual-band wifi router

Tags: wireless-networking, network-printer, dual-band

I have a DLink Dual Band dual band router. All the advanced devices in the house (laptops, iPad 3) are connected to the 5GHz 300MBs wireless-n band, and all the older devices are connected to the 2.4GHz wireless-g band.

I just bought a Brother HL-2270DW printer, and since it can only see wireless-g, it connected to the lower band.

My question is: in order to print, I need to switch to the lower band, print, and return to the higher one. Is there a way I can access the printer without switching network? Anything I should do on the router level, or the laptop?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It should work fine without switching frequency, those wireless devices on router should be bridged. Be sure that you have `Wlan partition` in advanced wireless settings `disabled`, when enabled it prevents wireless clients from communicating each other. What model are you using?

Comment: DLINK DIR-825 Dual Band

Comment: Got it! It was the `WLAN partition`! Please turn your comment to an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work fine without switching frequency, those wireless devices on router should be bridged.

Be sure that you have `Wlan partition` in advanced wireless settings `disabled`, when enabled it prevents wireless clients from communicating each other.

Name of this setting relates to `D-link` routers, on other devices may differ.

Comment: This also helped me too. For Linksys routers, it's called "AP Isolation".

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question/answer, but I attach my experience to it. I hadd a `D-Link` router as well, with dual wireless. In my case the `Wlan partition` was already `disabled` but I found that I had a `High protection` profile set for the `Firewall` (in the `Security` section). With that configuration, when my laptop was on the 5 ghz Wifi and the printer on the 2.4 ghz Wifi, if I tried to `ping` the printer from the laptop, all the packets were lost. Then i lowered the firewall/security setting to `Default protection` (or `Low protection`) and suddently I could ping the printer again, even though one was in the 5ghz and the other in the 2.4 ghz network, and the problem with the printer was fixed.

Hope this may help.