# Asus RT-AC66R, printer on 2.4 GHz network – how to disable WLAN partitioning to print from 5 GHz network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

I have an Asus RT-AC66R (best buy version of the RT-AC66U router). It has both a 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz network channels. I see them listed as separate SSID's.

Most of my devices connect to the 5 GHz, no problem. However, my printer only supports WiFi on the 2.4 GHz channel. This means whenever I go to print, I need to switch my laptop to the 2.4 GHz network before the printer is detected.

I'm pretty sure [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/512737/using-network-printer-on-a-dual-band-wifi-router) solves what I am trying to do, however the terminology must be different for my ASUS router as I cannot find that option in the settings.

Any idea how to disable "WLAN partitioning" on this router?

Comment: You're right about that it is this feature that you need. However there is no easy way to get rid of it on a ASUS RT-AC66R. (I've got an Asus RT-AC87U with the same issue.) The option just isn't available in the web-interface as far as I can tell. I hope someone comes up with a good answer on this question. I would like to know the solution too :-)

Comment: Why not setup the printer as a network printer, and you print to the IP address (or Netbios name) rather than WiFi Direct printing? Than it doesn't matter which network you are on, even a hard wired device can print, I do this with a Brother printer on a Asus RT-N66U (very similar router) and anything can print to it, wired, wireless, phones, etc. with no issues.

Comment: @acejavelin how did you set this up on your RT-N66U? This is the first printer I've owned in probably a decade so I'm a little behind the times. 

Comment: @Prefix - Depends on the printer, you to set it up as a network printer not a direct connect or WiFi direct printer. If you have a specific question, you should ask your own question.

Comment: I believe the option is called "Set AP Isolated" on your router.